# How to retrieve only time from prime ng date picker

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using datetime picker in primeng to show only the time picker

Here's the code that I have written :

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="classTimingsArray[i].start_time" timeOnly="true"></p-calendar>
```

As I have given timeOnly = true, I'm only getting timepicker which is what I want

But the value inside the ngModel is complete date along with the time (Wed Jan 17 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))

I only want the time to be retrieved

How should I do that?

Comment: Not PrimeFaces related... Please correct tagging

Comment: are you looking for time + timezone? or just time?

Comment: just time @pixelbits

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can handle the `onSelect` event in your template:

```
<p-calendar (onSelect)="onSelect($event)"
  [(ngModel)]="classTimingsArray[i].start_time" timeOnly="true">
</p-calendar>
```

From your component:

```
timeValue: string;

onSelect($event) {
  let hour = new Date($event).getHours();
  let min = new Date($event).getMinutes();
  if(min < 10) { 
     this.timeValue= `${hour}:0${min}`;
  } else {
     this.timeValue= `${hour}:${min}`;
  } 
}
```

Demo: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-e8lrz1?file=app%2Fcalendar%2Fcalendar.component.ts

Answer (score 9):

default dataType is Date but you can change it to string and you will be fine

`<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="classTimingsArray[i].start_time" timeOnly="true" dataType="string"></p-calendar>`

Answer (score 3):

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="classTimingsArray[i].start_time" timeOnly="true" dataType="string"></p-calendar>
```

> dataType="string"

by this time will be get as string like this **14:24**